# Nodemon Docker ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm getting this error when I do my restful requests to running nodemon server running inside Docker container:

```
12 Nov 14:41:37 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
12 Nov 14:41:37 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
12 Nov 14:41:37 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
12 Nov 14:41:37 - [nodemon] starting `node api.js -c config.json`
Server listening on port 8002
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.359Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running _sanitizePath
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.363Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running ?
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.364Z]  INFO:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: Got request: PUT /authentications/password
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.370Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running ?
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.371Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running bunyan
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.374Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running readBody
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.381Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running parseBody
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.382Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running parseQueryString
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.383Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running gzip
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.393Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running ?
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.397Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: running PUT_password
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.435Z] TRACE:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: response::send entered (code=200, headers={})
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
        at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
        at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.443Z] TRACE: User API/284 on ee7afec994f4: response sent
    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 14:41:41 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2014-11-12T14:41:41.444Z] DEBUG:  API/284 on ee7afec994f4: (req_id=0401aad0-6a7a-11e4-b06d-77810fe1ae21)
    Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
        at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
        at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

I have all the ports open that I could think of.

I can also curl the endpoints inside container manually with correct response. It seems though error is happening within node instance

Is there a reason why they're not working and throws this error?

Comment: just for test purpose, disable the gzip content enconding

Comment: @fmodos I tried but still same error

Comment: I tried with a dummy node example with no issue :( Could you provide Dockerfile / curl request in order to reproduce?